# Virtualbox Linux Adding SocketCAN Interface

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, canbus

Does anyone have experience using SocketCAN within Virtualbox? I'm using Xubuntu. I started by modprobing can, can_raw, can_dev and the relevant driver for the particular can module I'm using. In addition, I directed Virtualbox to pass through the CAN-USB device that I wanted to interface with.

When I ran the command `sudo ip link set can0 type can bitrate [bitrate]`, I got: Cannot find device 'can0'. I checked /dev, and I didn't find anything CAN related.

I ran `sudo dmesg | grep 'usb'`, and it looks like it is registered as a usb device, but not a CAN device.

Does anyone have any experience with SocketCAN? Is there some way to direct Linux to use a certain USB as a CAN socket?